# Approach to handle WiFi disconnects

Tags: android, network-programming, android-wifi

In my Android application, it is 
noticed that when the device goes to sleep/standby WiFi is 
disconnected. When the device wakes up, it gets reconnected. Before making a
httpClient.execute(..) call to remote server we check if the device is connected to n/w. 
When the data transfer is being done and if 
the device goes to sleep then Android runtime will switch to another 
medium for connectivity(3G,GPRS etc.).

1. Is the switch from WiFi to alternate cellular service 
   say 3G, seamless?
2. How do I wait for WiFi to become available again? Should I use Thread.sleep(delay) when the WiFi wakes up? I have seen broadcast actions when the WiFi state changes.

In general, what is the ideal approach to handling WiFi disconnects in a mobile app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use WifiManager.WifiLock when the transfer is happening and release it when you have finished.

I would suspect network connection switch would not be seamless.  I don't know for sure.

A BroadcastReceiver will let you know when Wifi connection state changes.  Have a look at ConnectivityManager though because that will monitor Wifi and GPRS etc and it does do failover.  Whether it is seamless though I don't know.